# Recovering just for me my deleted question (or answer)

Tags: support, deleted-questions, searching, moderators

I am sorry to ask. There was an MO Q. by me (which addressed in an elementary way *the infinity axiom, actually by just providing another formulation* of algebraic flavor). I have carelessly deleted my Q. without quite committing it to memory or other media.

I see that there is a bunch of related meta-questions about the deleted MO-posts but somehow I am not able to take advantage of them and the answers. I just see that any moderator can help--thus, please, help. Thank you.

Comment: For general reference: due to a recent change 10k+ users can search for their own deleted content with `deleted:1`

Comment: You have 11 deleted questions and 31 deleted answers, none of which seem to match your description.

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais -thank you for your time. It was definitely a **Q.** The question & answer format skews the text away from amplifying its intention or main point. Nevertheless there was something about groups and their finiteness or infiniteness, either way. I have presented what I believe was an original treatment of finiteness (or infiniteness)--it was all very simple & elementary. Possibly it was about a monoid (or semigroup) being forced to be a group. I hope that only $\mathbf 1$ my deleted Question fits my rough description while the remaining $\mathbf {10}$ are clearly not related.

Comment: The closest "question" I could find was [this one](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/173572/from-abstract-exp-to-mathbb-c-itself).

Comment: @S. Carnagan -- this is it, thank you very much.

Comment: Since 2022, it is possible to get a list of all your deleted questions/deleted answers through your profile. You can find more details here: [Can I somewhere see my own deleted questions?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/3254)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I somewhere see my own deleted questions?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/3254/can-i-somewhere-see-my-own-deleted-questions)