# Did few of my questions disappear without notification or trace?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

I strongly suspect one or two of my questions disappeared without
notification or trace on my user page in the last month.

Is this true?

Is there efficient algorithm to find links to the missing questions?

Do I need help from a moderator for this?

Comment: Since you have 10k+ reputation, you can see all your deleted post by searching for [deleted:1](https://mathoverflow.net/search?q=deleted%3A1). However, if they were relatively new posts, *deleted recent questions* should work, too. (And this is accessible also below 10k reputation.)
For more details see: [Can I somewhere see my own deleted questions?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/3254) (I am not sure whether the two questions should be considered duplicates, but they are definitely quite close to each other.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thank you, this appears to work. What does it mean "RemoveAbandonedQuestions"?

Comment: Most likely that it was [deleted by roomba](https://mathoverflow.net/help/roomba). (I believe there should be the following text under such question: "This question was automatically deleted. Please see the help center for more information." And it should contain the link I have given above.) You can find links to some further information [in this tag-info](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/auto-delete/info).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I somewhere see my own deleted questions?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/3254/can-i-somewhere-see-my-own-deleted-questions)

Comment: I am not sure to which extent the older post - [Can I somewhere see my own deleted questions?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/3254) - answers your question. I have flagged it as a duplicate - we will see whether other users agree with this assessment. (Or, if you feel there is something still to be added, you could edit your question to make it clearer in which aspects this question is different.)