# I lost my three questions

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-questions, moderation, moderators

About 3_4 days ago  3 questions of mine got down vote  but they were not "closed" or "onhold". After these downvotes, each of them became -1 vote, totally. Now I can not find these question. Where are my questions?

I just realize this situation. In fact yesterday I had 512 questions now I have 509 questions!

Comment: @GerryMyerson  what do you mean by "which"?They are disapeared so I can not show you the link.

Comment: I'd guess that ([meta-tag:support]) might be a more suitable tag that ([meta-tag:discussion]). (If I understood your question correctly, you're asking for help in finding the missing questions on the main. If I misunderstood your question, perhaps you should clarify what you want to discuss.)

Comment: I thought (if they were recent questions) that you might remember the *titles*, Ali. No matter, now that @Martin has found them.

Comment: If the three questions were downvoted three or four days ago, they should show up on the reputation tab or your user page (or maybe that doesn't apply to deleted questions?). If it turns out they were all downvoted in a brief interval, and by the same user (and the moderators should be able to tell), then the moderators can take action against the miscreant. I'd suggest flagging some other question of yours for moderator attention, explaining the situation, and seeing what they think.

Comment: @GerryMyerson  You have to check "show removed posts" in [your reputation tab](https://mathoverflow.net/users/current?tab=reputation) to see changes from deleted posts. I thought that this works only for 10k+ users, But now when I am [reading the documentation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139614/how-do-i-read-the-history-of-my-reputation/139615#139615) it does not seem to be the case: "When a post gets deleted, the question's title will be shown in plain text unless you are able to view the deleted post (10K users or the question owner)."

Comment: @GerryMyerson Maybe we could wait a bit whether the OP confirms that they can find the questions in the way suggested in your comment. But your solution is definitely much simpler that what I suggested - so probably you should post that as an answer. (I will just add to your comment that in the reputation tab the OP should be able see also the increase of the reputation after the question's were deleted, not only the decrease for the downvotes. As I've mentioned I am not entirely sure what are differences here between users above 10k and below 10k.)

Comment: @GerryMyerson  no they  were not recent. As you  said, fortunately Martin helped me  to  find them. Thank you for your  attention.I hope  I reopen at least two of them.

Comment: @GerryMyerson  Thanks  again  for  your  attention to my  problem.  Now the three questions  appeared in  MO. with my  best regards to you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since this question was posted, the situation has changed - now any user can find all their deleted posts. Simply go to your profile and in [the question tab](https://mathoverflow.net/users/current?tab=questions) you can click on "deleted questions" near the bottom.  Similarly, you can get to the list of your deleted answers through [the answers tab](https://mathoverflow.net/users/current?tab=answers).

See also:

- The section "Can I see a list of my deleted posts?" in the FAQ post: [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221).
- Various related posts on Meta Stack Exchange: [Show all of my question/answers to me even if they are deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2645), [Make your deleted questions and answers more discoverable](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/375071), [We should be able to find questions or answers that we have deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/13193), [How do I view my old deleted questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/217169), etc.
- [Is there any way to see my deleted questions or answers?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13948) on Mathematics Meta
- [Can I somewhere see my own deleted questions?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/3254) on this meta.

Despite the fact that now there is an easy way to find all of your deleted post, I left below the original version of the answer - perhaps the information included there might be useful in some other situations.

---

I have run a [SEDE](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/tags/data-explorer/info) query to list your questions: [Questions (id, title) of a given user](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/revision/1013692/1252372/questions-id-title-of-a-given-user)
. Since SEDE is updated once a week (you can see "Data updated Mar 17 at 8:47" in the [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/), these data still contain the posts which were posted before last week - even if they were deleted during this week.

You could download the query results after the update and compare the two files. However, I tried to check this manually and compare the list from SEDE with the list of questions in your profile. I found three following questions which seemed to be deleted at the moment.

- [A length decreasing homotopy of a closed curve in a simply connected manifold](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/285866/a-length-decreasing-homotopy-of-a-closed-curve-in-a-simply-connected-manifold) ([Google Cache](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:https://mathoverflow.net/questions/285866/a-length-decreasing-homotopy-of-a-closed-curve-in-a-simply-connected-manifold))
- [A differential operator associated with a vector field on the torus](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/272768/a-differential-operator-associated-with-a-vector-field-on-the-torus) ([Google Cache](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:https://mathoverflow.net/questions/272768/a-differential-operator-associated-with-a-vector-field-on-the-torus))
- [Integrability of distributions which are invariant under the isometry group](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/264043/integrability-of-distributions-which-are-invariant-under-the-isometry-group) ([Google Cache](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:https://mathoverflow.net/questions/264043/integrability-of-distributions-which-are-invariant-under-the-isometry-group))

Since you are the poster of those questions, now that you have links you should be able to access them.

I have checked whether they are available in the [Internet Archive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Archive), but I did not find any of these three questions there. As you can see, at the moment some version of the post is also available through Google cache (links are given above) - but I suppose that those cached links will stop working at some point.

Comment: Yes, it appears the three of them were [automatically deleted](https://mathoverflow.net/help/roomba).

Comment: Thank  you very much for your answer and your kind attention to my problem

Comment: @AliTaghavi I would be grateful if you could check whether you can find them in [your reputation tab](https://mathoverflow.net/users/current?tab=reputation) - as suggested by Gerry Myerson. (The checkbox called "show removed posts" should be checked.) That would be much easier way to find them - and information whether this really works could help other users who might have the same problem in the future.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your attention to my problem.Yes  the downvotes was in brief time. Moreover the questions had  interesting comments by  some participant. Now I can access my  question by clicking on the links you kindly provided.  But the second question had another title "a differential operator associated with a vector field on torous"

Comment: I checked "show remove box" I can find the titles of these three "removed" question . But the content of these questions are not available.  As O said above, I can access the question in the linked you provided. I would like to  say again that the down vote was in brief time. I clicked on the linked you provide and " undeleted" it but it is written " we need more 4 vote to reopen". I do not know whether other participant  access these questions for a possible vote to reopen.

Comment: I copy paste  2 questions of these 3 and i presented them in mse. I would like to say again that these questio s has intetesting comments.

Comment: Sorry for the incorrect title. (I have edited it now.) Probably I have copied a title of a different question from the results of the query by mistake.

Comment: @AliTaghavi I am a bit surprised that in the reputation tab you can see the titles and not the links. I expected the owner of the post to be able to get to the post in question. (I have already quoted the relevant part of the network-wide FAQ under your post: [How do I read the history of my reputation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139614#139615) "When a post gets deleted, the question's title will be shown in plain text unless you are able to view the deleted post (10K users or the question owner).")

Comment: In face, I have posted a bug report on Meta Stack Exchange: [Why the OP does not get link to the deleted post in the reputation tab?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/325612) We'll see whether somebody responds there - possibly we might find out whether this is the expected behavior or just a bug.

Comment: For the interested users, I'll add links to questions on Mathematics: [A differential operator associated with a vector field on the torus](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3158913) and [Integrability of distributions which are invariant under isometry group](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3158916).

Comment: @MartinSleziak  I  sincerely  thank you very much  for  your  valuable  help.  Now  my problem is  completely solved, the  question  appeared in  MO. My best regards to you.

Comment: @AliTaghavi Of course, you should keep in mind that if the questions staty at negative score (and without answer), they can get auto-deleted again: https://mathoverflow.net/help/roomba

Comment: I was considering whether this should simply be closed as a duplicate of: [Can I somewhere see my own deleted questions?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/3254) But maybe it doesn't hurt that the information about the new functionality - which makes finding your own deleted posts much easier now - is included here, too.