# How does one check progress towards a (second) Socratic badge?

Tags: support, badges

Not to take anything too seriously, but how does one check progress towards a (second) [Socratic badge](https://mathoverflow.net/help/badges/202/socratic)? I've seen a script for another Overflow site, but it doesn't seem to work here.

Comment: There is a feature request about this on [meta.se]: [Track next Socratic badge progress](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/271984). You might check the answers posted there to see whether there are some suggestions which might be useful. (And, of course, you can upvote that feature request if you think that it's a good idea.) Here is another related post: [How can we see our progress towards the next Socratic badge?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/328778) (The answer posted there suggests a SEDE query which could be considered as an estimate.)

Comment: There is also this post on Meta Stack Overflow: [I would like to track my next Socratic badge](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/318148). You wrote in the question: "I've seen a script for another Overflow site". Maybe if you include a link to the place where you saw it, somebody might be able to say whether it is possible to get it working on MO.

Comment: Thanks - this script seems to work: https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/919952/socratic-badge-progress  I guess I must have asked two well-received questions on the same day at least a dozen times :(

Comment: When putting [your userid in the query from the preceding comment](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/919952/socratic-badge-progress?userid=398), I see 192 days.

Comment: OK, eleven times.

Answer (score 5):

Although the question is about progress towards the specific badge, maybe it is useful to include also some details with a brief explanation how to run SEDE queries when you want a look at a specific site (in this case MathOverflow) and on a specific user. (You can find pointers to further information about SEDE [in the corresponding tag info](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/tags/data-explorer/info).)

The OP provided this SEDE query in a [comment](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/5216/how-does-one-check-progress-towards-a-second-socratic-badge#comment26795_5216): [Socratic badge progress](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/919952/socratic-badge-progress?userid=398)
.

- Notice that every SEDE query can be run on different sites — you have to choose MathOverflow. (You can also [choose MathOverflow Meta](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.mathoverflow/query/919952/socratic-badge-progress?userid=398) and various other sites.)
- The query has a parameter userid — where you have to enter your userid.
- You should also keep in mind that the data in this database are only updated once a week.
- As a side note, it is slightly better to be logged in on SEDE. (So that you do not have to solve a captcha when running a query.)

The userid is the number you can see in the URL and in the  search bar when you go to your profile page. (If you have accounts on several sites, userid on each of them will be different.) More details on this: [What is my user ID?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/98771)

---

Regarding the original question about badge progress towards the next Socratic badge, it might be useful to add some links.

- There is the following feature request on Meta Stack Exchange: [Track next Socratic badge progress](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/271984). In fact, [Glorfindel's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271984/track-next-socratic-badge-progress/317719#317719) to that question contains precisely the query mentioned above. (And it also mentions the warning that the query will not be precise.)
- There is also this post on Meta Stack Overflow: [I would like to track my next Socratic badge](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/318148). And one more related post on Meta Stack Exchange: [How can we see our progress towards the next Socratic badge?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/328778) In both cases, another SEDE query was suggested: [Progress towards Curious, Inquisitive and Socratic badges](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/229495/progress-towards-curious-inquisitive-and-socratic-badges?userid=398). (This one was created by Jon Ericson. Unlike Glorfindel's query, this one only counts the number of days — it does not check whether a user has a positive question record, which is the other requirement for this badge.) In this specific case, this query returns one more day than the other one (at the moment). The query contains a comment saying: "only posts closed within 60 days count against qualification". This might be a possible explanation for the difference (which could be caused by [Work of ICM 2010 plenary speakers (and other humans)](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/29485/revisions)).
- In case you want to examine more closely which days actually contribute to those numbers, here is [a query looking at individual days](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1542142/question-record-per-day?userid=398). It basically contains just one small part of the query linked above. (For example, if you sort the results by the number of questions, you can see the days when you asked more than one question.) You can find questions from a specific date using search with the parameters [user:me is:q created:YYYY-MM-DD](https://mathoverflow.net/search?q=user%3Ame+is%3Aq+created%3A2011-04-26). 10k+ users can also search among their deleted posts [by adding deleted:1](https://mathoverflow.net/search?q=user%3Ame+is%3Aq+created%3A2011-04-26+deleted%3A1).
- Those SEDE queries take into account only the questions which are not deleted. If you also want to review your deleted questions, here is a post saying how to find them: [Can I somewhere see my own deleted questions?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/3254)

I took the query created by Jon Ericson and modified it to a version which returns these numbers for more users, not just one. You can see here the result on the [main site](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1542318) and [on meta](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.mathoverflow/query/1542318). You can compare the results with the number of Socratic badges that various users have: [main](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1175429/users-with-most-badges-of-certain-kind?name=Socratic), [meta](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.mathoverflow/query/1175429/users-with-most-badges-of-certain-kind?name=Socratic).