# 1000 Questions by Dominic van der Zypen!

Tags: discussion, statistics, asking-questions, specific-user

Amazing milestone! Our first $1000$-question user.

[image]

> Question # $1000$:
> ["Edge sets on  maximal with respect to chromatic number"](https://mathoverflow.net/q/420450/6094).

Comment: Is Dominic our first 1000-question user? In any event, congratulations!

Comment: @TimCampion Users with most [posts](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1580473/users-with-most-posts-questions-answers), [questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1580478/users-with-most-questions). (Those SEDE queries can be run on any site.) Some SEDE queries posted here are tangentially related: [How does one check progress towards a (second) Socratic badge?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/5216) And you might also check who has [the most hot questions](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/9369/2020/4/16).

Comment: @TimCampion: Yes, as Martin's queries show. I added that. Thanks.

Comment: @MartinSleziak Maybe more interesting than merely counting posts would be non-CW question "[h-index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H-index)" / non-CW answer "h-index" (i.e. the maximum number $h$ such that a given user has at least $h$ non-CW questions / non-CW answers with score at least $h$) -- can you maybe write a SEDE query which computes this?

Comment: @StefanKohl I don't think that making such a query would be completely straightforward. I've posted your message [in the SEDE chatroom](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/1223/2022/4/16), maybe somebody might respond there. Or you could ask on Meta Stack Exchange. (I found a query written by somebody else which computes some kind of h-index for a single user: https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/45194/what-is-my-h-index?userid=28104)

Comment: I think we should strive for quality rather than quantity.

Comment: Incidentally, at least one of Dominic's questions led to a paper: https://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/3188/6094.

Comment: @StefanKohl Creating such query would be beyond my knowledge of SQL - but you can have a look [what other users suggested](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1223/conversation/calculating-h-index).

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thank you! Though, besides -- I think Emil Jerabek has hit the nail on the head, beyond all numerical indices.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek You have a point, but there is also something to be said for lowering one's filter a bit. If every question one asks is of very high quality, then I think it's likely that one has thrown out many valuable questions with the bathwater. With regard to Dominic in particular, I think his relentless inquisitiveness is something to celebrate! Our community is the richer for having him!

Comment: Thanks - I just stumbled over this by googling my own name... Thanks Joseph for the post, and also to the commenters!

Comment: I totally understand Emil's point of view - and at the same time, a big thank you to everyone, and thanks Tim - and apologies for the (not so few) rubbish questions I have to delete soon after posting.