# Tracing and Seeing deleted questions

Tags: support

Is there a way to search through deleted questions? Can a user reach his or her own old deleted questions?

In the early days of MO I asked about similar sites in related disciplines and there were a few useful answers with many links. The question was closed, but the information there was nevertheless useful. Now the question disappeared completely and I cannot see how to access it myself.

Comment: I realized that. I suppose the question was deleted long time ago. My current question is indeed how to trace it.

Comment: You can always get a list of your own deleted posts (regardless of how old) by entering *deleted:1* into the search field. -- Deleted posts by other users are searchable only for moderators.

Comment: @StefanKohl thanks!

Comment: Related: [Can I somewhere see my own deleted questions?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/3254) and [Recovering just for me my deleted question (or answer)](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/2735).

Comment: Looking at your post in the "[Requests for reopen and undelete votes for on-hold, closed, and deleted questions](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/223/requests-for-reopen-and-undelete-votes-for-on-hold-closed-and-deleted-question/4468#4468)" thread, I see that you find the question you've been looking for. Maybe you could post an answer explaining how you found it - that might be useful for other users with a similar problem.

Comment: It is now easy to find the list of your own deleted questions through your profile page - this was added to the Stack Exchange software in January 2022. And 10k+ users can can also [search among their own deleted questions](https://mathoverflow.net/search?q=deleted%3A1): Details are explained here (the answer was updated to reflect the new feature): [Can I somewhere see my own deleted questions?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/3254)